# Is using system.environment.newline and culture independent .ToString() for parsing going to cause me problems

Tags: c#, parsing, save, tostring

I've worked on several projects before where I use System.Environment.Newline as a separator for a save file I later parse.

All of those times, it's been in a windows only environment I knew - I'm making one for a game I'm working on that will be released to mac and linux as well. Is saving and parsing these on multi platforms going to be a problem? I'm parsing for \n and catching \r's.

I also use .ToString() for int conversion with no culture specification - will this ever bring back an issue in ints? I assume it would with floats as it could be 35.5 or 35,5, but parsing either should bring back 35.5 in the system.

Comment: Both inventing your own file format and not following recommendations about serialization of values using InvariantCulture seem like a bad ideas... But there is no way for anyone but you to know if it is actually problem or not. Testing with different line breaks/cultures is trivial - so not exactly clear what specific answer you are looking for.

Comment: Don't assume that the culture only affects the [NumberDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator) - it's possible for a culture to specify the [`NegativeSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign) (though I don't think any "built-in" cultures do this), and the [`NumberNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbernegativepattern) (e.g. -123.456.ToString() in Arabic is "123.456-" since they read right-to-left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with multiple OSes, then the short answer is yes. But it's also trivial to fix.

For line endings, you can normalize EOL with regex (or plain ol' `string.Replace`) such that `\r` when **not** followed by `\n` becomes just `\n`, and `\r\n` becomes just `\n`. Or even more simply: don't use `Environment.NewLine` at all and just standardize to `\n`, which is probably the best option.

If you want your `ToString` calls (and any subsequent `int.Parse` calls) to ignore culture, use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) when possible. It will solve any and all (de)serialization issues you may run across.

Comment: Thanks. Since I'd dealt mostly with only windows/english north american cultured computers, I hadn't had this problem before.

Putting the tostring/cultureinvariant and switching environment.newline to /r/n was what I was thinking of doing to fix it anyway, was just looking for a second voice that it was a good practice.